# uitableview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths not working

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, tableview

I have a `tableviewcell` in the `RegisterViewController`, when i click on it, it push to the `SelectCityViewController` where i can pick a city from a `uipickerview`. and I have defined a delegate in the `SelectCityViewController`. But when i implement the delegate method, i got the city back from the `pickerview` and the selected `indexpath` from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in `RegisterViewController`. When i check the log, i get the city, and the selected `indexpath`. but when i call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`, the cell still got the old titlelabel text. the code:

```
SelectCityViewController.h

@protocol SelectCityDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)didGetCity:(City *)city;

@end

SelectCityViewController.m

- (void)finished:(UIBarButtonItem *)buttonItem
{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didGetCity:)]) {
        [self.delegate didGetCity:self.city];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", self.city.city);
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

RegisterViewController.m

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 2) {
        self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
        UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        SelectCityViewController *signUp = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SignVC"];
        signUp.delegate = self;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:signUp animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)didGetCity:(City *)city
{
    NSLog(@"%@", city.city);
    NSLog(@"%@", selectedIndexPath);
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = city.city;
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[selectedIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

Comment: any error? If error occur after reloading your tableview then edit your question with error log.

Comment: No error. The titlelabel.text just don't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the below code you don't have to set the value here, because when you will reload, it will override the value with what is in the function where you are creating your cells.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath];
cell.textLabel.text = city.city;
```

Just reload the cell, and put above code in your

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   //Cell intialization and other things

      cell.textLabel.text = city.city;
}
```

Comment: @[selectedIndexPath] is an array. It's identical to what you wrote, just using the new array literal syntax.

Comment: But when the app runs at first, I have already set the cell's text to cell.textLabel.text = @"Choose a city"; And when i click this cell, it should push a view controler where i can choose a city from a pickerview, then back to this cell, i want this cell's text change to city.city.

Comment: you can do if(city==nil){ cell.textLabel.text = @"Choose a city"; }else{ cell.textLabel.text = city.city; } considering city will not be initialized in the start..

Answer (score 1):

`didGetCity` needs to update the model that backs the table, not the table cell itself.  How do you answer `numberOfRowsInSection:`?  With the count of some array?

That array at index `selectedIndexPath.row` needs to change.  `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` should  initialize the cell with that same data.  Then your didGetCity method updates the array and reloads.  It should not refer to cells.

Comment: The city cell is a static cell in the indexpath.section = 2.

Comment: numberOfRowsInSection just retun 1 for this section 2. in section 1,i got another array backs the table.